# Python was not found when running createDataFrame with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run park in windows. I can open spark with the `spark` command on the anaconda terminal and it works. I can create a list as well but when I try to `show()` a data frame I get the following message and error:

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

and the error is

```
 raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o52.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (LAPTOP-4407EI48 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
```

The commands I run inside pyspark shell are:

```
# Create DataFrame in PySpark Shell
data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
```

as instructed in [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/install-pyspark-in-anaconda-jupyter-notebook/).

I have set the following environment variables with the corresponding installations as explained [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/how-to-install-and-run-pyspark-on-windows/).

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351
PATH = %PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\bin

SPARK_HOME  = C:\apps\opt\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop2
HADOOP_HOME = C:\apps\opt\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop2
PATH=%PATH%;C:\apps\opt\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop2\bin
```

Comment: I think the error message is very descriptive, you need Python to run Pyspark. The commands you ran in pyspark shell are Python codes. Type `python --version` in your shell to check if Python is installed. Then follow instructions to install Python on Windows with this link: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/.

Comment: I would recommend you run spark on WSL instead. It's tricky to get it working in windows.

Comment: I definitely have python installed I am running an anaconda virtual environment with python 3.9.15. it looks like it is looking for python as if it was installed without anaconda